# PHP - Searching a way to put sql data to "option" tag in HTML

Tags: php, html, sql

First of all, i'm going to try my best to explain you what's my problem. English is not my mother language. Secondly i just start learning `php`/`html`/`sql`.

So, i was searching a way to display data from `SQL` in `HTML` using `PHP`.
I want to display data in an `option` tag. like a country `select` form.
Here's my primary file which is a `.php` file

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1></h1> 
    <form method="get" action="deptoreg.php"</form>
        <select name='nom'>
          <?php 
             $reg=getRegion();
             foreach ($reg as $item):
          ?>
           <option class="reg"><?= $item['id'] ?> - <?= $item['region'] ?></option>
        </select>
         <?php endforeach; ?>


        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send" />
        <footer if="foot">Site réalisé en PHP, HTML5 et CSS par Victor Lehouck</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's my other php file i'm calling to get functions

```
<?php

function display_reg()
{
   $region = departement_to_region();
   echo ($region);
}

function getDatabase()
{
   $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=container_db;charset=utf8', 
   'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
   return $bdd;
}

function get_departement()
{
   $var =  $_GET['nom'];
   $bdd = getDatabase();
   $dep=$bdd->prepare("SELECT departements, region_id_region FROM departement 
   WHERE departements = ?");
   $dep->execute(array($var));
   $data=$dep->fetch();
   $id = $data[1];
   return $id;
}

function departement_to_region()
{
   $bdd = getDatabase();
   $id = get_departement();
   $reg=$bdd->prepare("SELECT departement FROM region WHERE id_region = ?");
   $reg->execute(array($id));
   $data_reg=$reg->fetch();
   $ret = $data_reg[0];
   return $ret;
}

function getRegion()
{
   $bdd = getDatabase();
   $result= $bdd->query('SELECT id_region AS id, departement AS region FROM region ORDER BY region');
   return $result;
} 
?>
```

But the problem is that only one of the items is displaying in the option and the other ones are just displayed as a text after.
Thanks in advance for the answer(s).

Comment: your closing form tag is in the wrong spot. Would you like me to make this an answer? *heh!*

Comment: What you basically want to do is to store the sql data in a row and then call them in to option tag of html using id correct ?

Comment: `<form method="get" action="deptoreg.php"</form>` this contains 2 errors here.

Comment: I'm voting this out as a typo.

Comment: Alcaeus D : That's exactly what i want to do!

Funk Forty Niner : I'm actually trying, not finding at all...
                              But i keep trying things!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you form should looks like this

```
<form method="get" action="deptoreg.php">
    <select name='nom'>
        <?php 
            $reg=getRegion();
            foreach ($reg as $item): 
        ?>
        <option class="reg" value="<?= $item['id'] ?>"> <?= $item['region'] ?></option>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
I really need to work more on HTML syntax!
Have a good day!

Answer (score 3):

Switch this lines:

```
</select>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This way:

```
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Also you close `form` too early:

```
 <form method="get" action="deptoreg.php"</form>
```

Correct code:

```
<form method="get" action="deptoreg.php">
```

And add closing tag `</form>` after last `input`

Comment: you missed something here.

Comment: I did no understand what. Please help @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: look at the other answer and the OP's code again and [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48462320/php-searching-a-way-to-put-sql-data-to-option-tag-in-html/48462414?noredirect=1#comment83917653_48462320) I left under the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too, Hope it will be more helpful.

```
<?php

$reg = getRegion();

foreach($reg as $item)
{
// append new option everytime the loop iterates.
$option .= "<option class='"reg"' value='".$item['id']."'>'".$item['region']."'</option>";
}

?>

<form method = "get" action = "deptoreg.php">
    <select name="nom">
    <?php if(isset($option)) echo $option; ?>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```